# What's really the difference between front wheel drive and rear wheel drive?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, free-body-diagram

I searched many articles and what I found is power transfer to respective wheels and shift of centre of gravity etc. But what's really the difference between two FBDs and dynamics?

Comment: well drawing the FBD should be easy enough to see the difference between the two, which would then end up being an engineering question as to what difference they'd be